# Multi-threading in C# (.Net 4.5) for monte-carlo

Tags: c#, multithreading, montecarlo

I have been tasked with taking a monte-carlo model and using multi-threading to make it run faster. As it's monte-carlo, each simulation is independent of the next. I want to manually create each thread as each one will be running many thousands of simulations and storing each simulation result in a database and I want to create as many threads as there are cores in the processor and give them a high priority.

Here is the core code used to manage this (I am testing with a small number of simulations):

```
        var threads = new List<Thread>();
        iNumCores = Environment.ProcessorCount;
        iSims = 64;

        iNumSimsPerThread = iSims / iNumCores;
        for (int iThread = 0; iThread < iNumCores; iThread++)
        {
            iStart = (iThread * iNumSimsPerThread) + 1;
            iEnd = ((iThread + 1) * iNumSimsPerThread);

            Thread thread = new Thread(() => ProcessParallelMonteCarloTasks(iStart, iEnd, iSims));
            thread.Priority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal;
            thread.Start();
            threads.Add(thread);
        }
        foreach (var thread in threads)
            thread.Join();
```

My machine has 8 cores, so this test should create 8 threads, each running 8 simulations. When I write the resultant data to the database, I include the simulation number. I would expect to see 64 rows with 1 per simulation.

However, I get 1 row per simulation up to 40 and then a gap until 57 and then 3 rows for each simulation between 57 and 64.

[image: SQL Server results]

Unfortunately, I can't debug a thread and so have no idea what's going on and why it's missing some simulations and running multiple copies of others. When I have task manager open, I can see that 3-4 cores are remaining unused while the program runs.

Any thoughts?

UPDATE:
Following Andre's feedback, I looked at the scheduling of threads and the execution of the 'ProcessParallelMonteCarloTasks' function.

The first thing I noticed is that some threads were timing out connecting to the database. I changed the min pool size to equal the number of cores and that fixed that problem, but here is the order in which threads are created and the 'ProcessParallelMonteCarloTasks' gets run:

[Execution order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VewGv.jpg)

In this instance, the simulation ranges '17-24', '41-48' and '57-64' are called twice and '1-8', '25-32' and '49-56' are missing.

UPDATE 2:
I have been watching my Task Manager as this runs and set the thread priority to the highest. What I see suggests that 3 threads are running on 1 core, 2 threads on 2 cores and 1 thread on a fourth core. The other 4 cores are pretty much idle. Is there any way I can get it to run 1 thread per core? The overhead of running 3 threads on a single core must be large.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about your question? I'm not sure if this is a multi-threading problem or a simple sql INSERT problem. Do you save to the database as soon as one task is complete or do you wait for all the simulations to complete and, only then, save to the database? If the latter is true, then how do you save each one of the results? In a List<T>? A Dicionary<TKey, TValue> ...?

Comment: It's not a problem with the INSERT - the pre-threading version works just fine. When each simulation completes, I write the data to the database (for audit trail purposes, we need to capture the results of each simulation per asset). Results consist of some individual numbers and some arrays. The arrays are converted to a string.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code you posted. The problem is probably somewhere else (maybe in ProcessParallelMonteCarloTasks)

Comment: Andre, I found an issue with the database connection timing out, but still having a problem with some of the threads not running and others duplicating - please see update to original post.

Comment: Have you considered using a Parallel.For instead?  `Parallel.For(0, 64, i=>ProcessParallelMonteCarloTasks(i, i, 1));` is pretty simple.  Also, adjusting the thread priority isn't going to magically make your code run faster, and in most cases just causes issues. Or use PLINQ: `Enumerable.Range(0,64).AsParallel().ForAll(i=>ProcessParallelMonteCarloTasks(i, i, 1)));`

Comment: Robert, my main driver is to get as much control over the threading as possible and the info I had seen suggested that threads were a better solution than parallel.for. If you can point me at something otherwise, I would appreciate the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`iStart` and `iEnd` need to be fresh variables, iow declare them inside your loop, else (they are free) and you end up capturing mutated values as used.

Comment: Leppie - that's perfect. It has fixed my probem! Many thanks for your help with this.

Comment: @John I'd also consider at the very least staging results somewhere else other than SQL (even if you transfer them to SQL later on).

Comment: Jonathan - I have been considering that. I do need to show the aggregated results when the simulations have finished but there isn't an immediate need to get the granular data. What are your thoughts on the most efficient way of staging the data before writing to the database?

Comment: @John: Nothing wrong with offloading results via another async task or message queue (I highly doubt there is any near real-time requirement, but within a few seconds is good enough).

Comment: What I do with a simulator I have is to store the results in a ConcurrentBag<SimulationResult>. Also, you should take a look at `Parallel.For` and `Parallel.ForEach`. They do all the hard work you're doing there (they decide automatically the number of threads, automatically split the work evenly along threads, etc...)

Comment: @Andre - I did a quick test this morning, where I ran the multi-threaded simulations without saving individual results to the database and the speed pickup was incredible - about 95% of the execution time is taken up with DB writes. I will take a look at the ConcurrentBag idea - it looks like a good solution to this problem.

Comment: @John: If the results are small enough, keeping it in memory would be best.

Comment: Also, take a look at Parallel.For. It will probably fix the core/thread distribution problem you mentioned.
And oh, remember to mark @leppie 's answer as the answer if it has fixed your problem.